# Scope of the @extend-only selectors (placeholders) in SASS

Tags: css, scope, sass, extend, placeholder

I thought the following SCSS would end in error when compiling:

```css
.main {

  %abstract {
    color: red;
  }

  .main-element {
    @extend %abstract;
  }

}

.outside {
  @extend %abstract; // <-- 
}
```

While it actually compiles to:

```css
.main .main-element, .main .outside {
  color: red;
}
```

Is there any way to make such placeholders not available ouside the *scope*, i.e. only available for children of `.main`?

See http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders

Comment: You just wrote a placeholder that is only available for `.main-element` and `.outside` inside of `.main`. Maybe I just don't get it. But could you explain what you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/xBkw9/

Comment: @NicoO I would like the `%abstract` placeholder to be only available for the children of `.main`. That is, since `.outside` is not a child of `.main` (but a sibling), I would like the compiler to fail.

Comment: I don't think you can get the compiler to throw an error at this point. Maybe there is a solution to at least use` @warn "Not to be used outside of..." `, but I'am not sure how to implement that and even if, it would not be a solid solution for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  Nesting only provides scope to variables (as of Sass 3.3) or mixins, not selectors.  A placeholder class is the same as any other class, except for the part where its name is not output in the compiled CSS.

If this behavior is required, then you're stuck using mixins (which can, in turn extend the desired selector)

```
%foo {
  color: red;
}

.main {

  @mixin foo() {
    @extend %foo;
  }

  .main-element {
    @include foo();
  }

}

.outside {
  @include foo(); // <-- yep, it errors here
}
```

Comment: Great solution, I didn't know mixins were *scoped when nested*.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use @at-root

```
%abstract {
  color: red;
}

.main {

  .main-element {
    @extend %abstract;

    @at-root .outside {
      @extend %abstract;
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
.main .main-element, .outside {
  color: red;
}
```

or just move the placeholder outside specific main block

```
%abstract {
    color: red;
  }

.main {

  .main-element {
    @extend %abstract;
  }
}

.outside {
  @extend %abstract;
}
```